# Add type to sublime C++ syntax

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I am using SublimeText 3 to code C++. I would like to have some new type be treated an highlighted as basic types.

So

```
myString
```

would highlight like

```
int
```

Comment: All the files you need are [here](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/tree/master/C%2B%2B). Have at it.

Comment: That is a bunch of files with which I have no good idea what to do with?